# How to initialize value by another value in initializer list in Rust?

Tags: initialization, rust

For example we may take [this code:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=867bce90df7337a94c4cf7cbbea0ab51&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct B;

struct A {
    obj: Rc<B>,
}
impl A {
    fn new(obj: Rc<B>) -> A {
        A {
            obj: obj,
        }
    }
}
struct C {
    b: Rc<B>,
    a: A,
}
impl C {
    fn new() -> C {
        C {
            b: Rc::new(B),
            a: A::new(b.clone()),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

}
```

Here is a `A` struct member called `a` which I want to initialize by another value in same initializer list. I think it is not possible so I usually use `Option<T>` to do it:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct B;

struct A {
    obj: Rc<B>,
}
impl A {
    fn new(obj: Rc<B>) -> A {
        A {
            obj: obj,
        }
    }
}
struct C {
    b: Rc<B>,
    a: Option<A>,
}
impl C {
    fn new() -> C {
        let mut c = C {
            b: Rc::new(B),
            a: None,
        };
        c.a = Some(A::new(c.b.clone()));
        c
    }
}

fn main() {

}
```

But in my opinion this is stupid because I do useless extra work here and later I need to always unwrap this option. Is there any way to do this more simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating the value first?

```
impl C {
    fn new() -> C {
        let tmp = Rc::new(B);
        C {
            b: tmp.clone(),
            a: A::new(tmp),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, you made my day. Don't know why I did not do that earlier.